# Django: How to get related data from different db tables and display it as one

Tags: django, model, html-rendering

I have this two models which creates my tables, now my question is, how can I get only home_team and away_team fields on Events table then get odd from Bets table and display it in one match

```
class Event(models.Model):
    sport_id = models.ManyToManyField(Sport)
    league_id = models.ManyToManyField(League)
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    match_date = models.DateField()
    match_time = models.TimeField()
    featured = models.IntegerField()


class Bet(models.Model):
    league_id = models.ManyToManyField(League)
    match_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Event',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    bet_id = models.IntegerField()
    bet_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    choice_id = models.IntegerField()
    choice_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    odd = models.FloatField()
    match_date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bet = Bet.objects.get(id=ID)
home_team = bet.match_id.home_team
away_team = bet.match_id.away_team
odd = bet.odd
```

> ID is the bet id you are trying to access

For more reference you may visit django 3 official documentation for [many-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)